# mysqli query for multiple cases with coditions

Tags: mysql

Need to select data if condition first true then check user id exist, if condition not true then check condition two then check user id not exist

Technologies used: Codigniter - Mysqli

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
OR `user_id` IN('62', '63', '58', '6', '50', '19', '2', '17', '7', '3')
AND `user_id` NOT IN('35')
OR (CASE WHEN except_friends = 1 THEN FIND_IN_SET('1', friends_list), FALSE END CASE WHEN selected_friends = 1 THEN NOT FIND_IN_SET('1', friends_list), FALSE END) ORDER BY `id` desc
```

Mysql syntax error

Comment: there should be a else before  ```FALSE END``` replacing the comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is syntax error in your query. try this one

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
 WHERE user_id = '1' 
    OR user_id IN('62', '63', '58', '6', '50', '19', '2', '17', '7', '3') 
    AND user_id NOT IN('35') 
    OR 
    (CASE 
        WHEN except_friends = 1 
            THEN NOT FIND_IN_SET('1', friends_list)
        WHEN selected_friends = 1 
            THEN NOT FIND_IN_SET('1', friends_list)
    END) ORDER BY id desc
```